# Cplex arrays in constrains

Tags: cplex, opl

I have used the below code to generate [1 3 3 3 2 2 5 5 5 5 5]
I have a decision variable array c[n] where n equal the same range/size of s{} and i want every value in this decision variable to be less than these value in s{} i wrote the below code and there are no errors but the values of c[n] are not forced to be less than the values of s{} c[1] is not <= 1 and c[2] is not <=3

```
int n=4;
range r=1..n;
int m=11;
range w=1..m;


int a[r]=[1,3,2,5];

tuple t
{
  key int rank;
  int value;
}

{t} s={};

dvar c[w];

subject to 
{

  forall( k in w, i in 1.. card(s) )
           c [k]  <= item(s,<i>).value ;

}

execute
{
  var rank=0;
  for(var i in r)
  {
    for(var j=1;j<=a[i];j++)
    {
      rank++;
      s.add(rank,a[i])
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do the preprocess before the subject to block.

Try

```
int n=4;
range r=1..n;
int m=11;
range w=1..m;


int a[r]=[1,3,2,5];

tuple t
{
  key int rank;
  int value;
}

{t} s={};

execute
{
  var rank=0;
  for(var i in r)
  {
    for(var j=1;j<=a[i];j++)
    {
      rank++;
      s.add(rank,a[i])
    }
  }
}

dvar int c[w];

subject to 
{

  forall( k in w, i in 1.. card(s) )
           c [k]  <= item(s,<i>).value ;

}
```

Comment: Sir for the execute function or preprocess i do it after the subject to block because it depends on a decision variable which generated in subject to block, So how to  do the execute in the above code before the subject to with depending on a DV in the subject to block???

Comment: Then you could use a main to do many solves as in https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooflowcontrolregenerate.mod

Comment: Dear dr. alex i have asked you another question in stack overflow could you please answer it